# Pandas explode and drop duplicates for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am having some issues when trying to perform `explode` on multiple (4) columns. The first problem is that I run into `MemoryError` if I try to explode all the columns at once. There are many duplicates after exploding each column individually so I could use `drop_duplicates()`, however since there are `lists` in the columns it raises `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. If I convert the columns to strings with `astype(str)` then these columns cannot be used with `.explode()`. So if I try to `pd.eval()` the column before performing the second `.explode()` I get `UndefinedVariableError: name 'nan' is not defined`. This is the example data set:

```
    id     col_1      col_2   col_3   col_4 
0    1 ['a','b']        nan   ['c']     nan   
1    2       nan  ['d','e']     nan     nan
2    3     ['f']        nan     nan     nan
3    4       nan      ['g']     nan     nan 
4    5       nan        nan   ['h']     nan
5    6       nan        nan   ['i']   ['j']
```

This is the current code:

```
for i in new_table:
    new_table = new_table.explode(i)
    new_table = new_table.astype(str)
    new_table = new_table.drop_duplicates()
    new_table['col_1'] = pd.eval(new_table['col_1'])
    new_table['col_2'] = pd.eval(new_table['col_2'])
    new_table['col_3'] = pd.eval(new_table['col_3'])
    new_table['col_4'] = pd.eval(new_table['col_4'])
```

The `pd.eval()` raises `UndefiniedVariableError: name 'nan' is not defined`. If I remove the last 4 lines, then the columns are interpreted as strings and in the second loop, the `explode()` doesn't do anything because the input is a string, not a list. However I **must(?)** convert the columns to strings to perform the `drop_duplicates()`.

Code for recreating example dataset:

```
new_table = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                          'col_1':[['a','b'],np.nan,['f'],np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                          'col_2':[np.nan,['d','e'],np.nan,['g'],np.nan,np.nan],
                          'col_3':[['c'],np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,['h'],['i']],
                          'col_4':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,['j']]})
```

Expected output:

```
id     col_1      col_2   col_3   col_4 
1          a        nan       c     nan
1          b        nan       c     nan
2        nan          d     nan     nan
2        nan          e     nan     nan
3          f        nan     nan     nan
4        nan          g     nan     nan
5        nan        nan       h     nan
6        nan        nan       i       j
```

Comment: are they actual lists(not a str repr of a list)? if they are can you post the code to recreate the dataframe? also an expected output would help. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, they are actual lists. Editing now... The only thing to keep in mind is that these lists contain more than 2 items and there are over 30k rows, so exploding all columns generate `memoryerror`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you to something like this:

```
df[['id']].join((df[i].explode() for i in df.iloc[:,1:]))
```

Output:

```
|    |   id | col_1   | col_2   | col_3   | col_4   |
|---:|-----:|:--------|:--------|:--------|:--------|
|  0 |    1 | a       | nan     | c       | nan     |
|  0 |    1 | b       | nan     | c       | nan     |
|  1 |    2 | nan     | d       | nan     | nan     |
|  1 |    2 | nan     | e       | nan     | nan     |
|  2 |    3 | f       | nan     | nan     | nan     |
|  3 |    4 | nan     | g       | nan     | nan     |
|  4 |    5 | nan     | nan     | h       | nan     |
|  5 |    6 | nan     | nan     | i       | j       |
```

Note, I think the main difference in what you're doing and what I am doing, is that you are using `explode` on a dataframe, hence your dataframe is duplicated for every column you are calling.  Then you are selecting only your "exploded" columna and joining to the new dataframe.

What I am doing is exploding each column(pd.Series) and join the results of each "exploded" series together on index.  I am not creating a bunch of extra columns that are created when you use explode on a dataframe.

Comment: Well, this doesn't drop the duplicates as I'm running into 51M+ rows, but it doesn't generate `MemoryError` so it should be fine to perform the `drop_duplicates()` on.

Comment: I'm not exploding on the full dataframe. By using the loop, I'm exploding on each column (series) individually, no extra columns being added in either solution. This will generate duplicate rows (both on your and my solution), that need to be dropped intermediately after each `.explode()` otherwise the size of the dataframe becomes unmanageable (`.drop_duplicates()` has been running for over 15 minutes now). Using `drop_duplicates()` after each `explode()` ensures the dataframe maintains a healthy size.

Comment: `df.explode(columname)` yield a new dataframe with extra columns. Now s.explode(), where s is a pd.Series only yields that column and the index.  See the difference?   If you modified your loop to use `df['columnname'].explode()` I think it would be less memory usage.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't find anything about extra columns in the documentations, examples nor when I run it on smaller files. However yes, I agree about the memory usage, because your code did run, while mine generated memory error.

Comment: Run a test case. `df.explode('col_1')` vs `df['col_1'].explode()`

Comment: Reading from the example in pandas documentation, there is no extra column added, I do agree there might be memory usage differences though.

Comment: Okay, it finished running now, I'm finding myself with 24M columns, surprised with the number, but it can't be wrong as everything makes logical sense. The upvote is there because the answer is functional and gets the job done. I was hoping for something a bit more efficient with the intermediate `drop_duplicates()` after each explode. If no other (better) answer comes by, I'll accept it as well. Thanks a lot Scott.

Comment: @CeliusStingher see pervious edit comment.  [pd.DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) returns a DataFrame is different from [pd.Series.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) returns a Series.

Comment: No problem.  Happy coding!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207532/discussion-between-celius-stingher-and-scott-boston).

Answer (score 2):

I had another way using `stack` , then `explode()`, `cumcount` and `unstack` which I thought you can give a try.

```
s= new_table.set_index('id').stack(dropna=True).explode().to_frame('s')
final = (s.set_index(s.groupby(s.index.get_level_values(-1))
                              .cumcount(),append=True)['s'].unstack(1))
final = final.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 
                      x.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates().droplevel(1)
```

---

```
print(final)

    col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4
id                        
1      a   NaN     c   NaN
1      b   NaN     c   NaN
2    NaN     d   NaN   NaN
2    NaN     e   NaN   NaN
3      f   NaN   NaN   NaN
4    NaN     g   NaN   NaN
5    NaN   NaN     h   NaN
6    NaN   NaN     i     j
```

Comment: Thank you Anky! I'm pretty scared by the performance using `stack`, `explode`, groupby and a lambda later on. It does the job though.

Comment: @CeliusStingher I understand. I was hoping to find a way without a for loop (*agree this is an experimental answer*) but couldnt avoid the lambda since both `ffill` and `bfill` was needed in each group. :)